# Javascript random paragraphs swap, in any random order

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

Trying to swap the paragraphs at any random order with a button click using javascript, tried putting the paragraphs in an array and making a swap function.. Please let me know if I'm missing anything
(My first post ever!)

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Swap Paragraphs At Random</title>
 <script>

    window.onload = function () {
    var x = document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML;
    var y = document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML;
    var z = document.getElementById('p3').innerHTML;
    var lists = [x,y,z];
    var swapped = false;

    document.getElementById('trigger').onclick = function swap() {

        if (swapped == false) {
            document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * lists.length);
            document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * lists.length);
            swapped = true;
            return swapped;


        } else {
            document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = "" + x;
            document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML = "" + y;
            swapped = false;
            return swapped;
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="p1">Loren sump dolor sit mate, sumo unique argument um no. </div><br>

<div id="p2"> Id mes mover elect ram assertion has no. </div><br>

<div id="p3">Ea augur diam usu, nosier arum est an. </div><br>

<button id="trigger" onlick="swap()">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is not working? You need to explain where things are breaking so we can help

Comment: is there an issue there ?

Comment: Having a quick look, first off you are just assigning the "swapped" paragraphs to the random number you have generated so they become a number instead of your text. You also dont even do anything with the 3rd paragraph.

Comment: The binding (associating the event with the function) is not being done properly.
I mean, it is redundant to add the onclick attribute to the html element when you are already binding the event in the script. That will proabaly cause the function to be triggered twice for every click. but not in this case because you also mistyped onclick (onlick)

Comment: Also, the ' "" + x ' expression is the same as just ' x '

Answer (score 1):

Get all your elements with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and transform it into an array of elements with [`Array#from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

To retrieve and delete an element from the list use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

- Only when the user clicks do you actually get the paragraphs and put them into the list.
- Then for each element, you set a random paragraph to it and then you remove that paragraph from the list.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.container > div'));

  document.getElementById('trigger').onclick = function swap() {

      const list = elements.map(ele=>ele.innerHTML);
      
      elements.forEach(ele=>{
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
        ele.innerHTML = list.splice(index, 1)
      });

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Loren sump dolor sit mate, sumo unique argument um no. </div>

  <div> Id mes mover elect ram assertion has no. </div>

  <div>Ea augur diam usu, nosier arum est an. </div>
</div>

<button id="trigger" onlick="swap()">Click</button>
```

Comment: @MaheerAli yes that's normal. Sometiems Math.random returns the same index as to the current location of the paragraph.

Comment: I know that but that should be fixed I think

Answer (score 0):

Well, If I get it correctly, all you want is to `swap` the value of those `div`s.
Your code is perfectly fine, you missed just `1` thing, pay attention:-

you are doing `Math.floor(Math.random() * lists.length)` instead of `lists[Math.floor(Math.random() * lists.length)]` in `if (swapped == false) {` section

```
document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = lists[Math.floor(Math.random() * lists.length)];
document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML = lists[Math.floor(Math.random() * lists.length)];
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Swap Paragraphs At Random</title>
 <script>

    window.onload = function () {
    var x = document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML;
    var y = document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML;
    var z = document.getElementById('p3').innerHTML;
    var lists = [x,y,z];
    var swapped = false;

    document.getElementById('trigger').onclick = function swap() {

        if (swapped == false) {
            document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = lists[Math.floor(Math.random() * lists.length)];
            document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML = lists[Math.floor(Math.random() * lists.length)];
            swapped = true;
            return swapped;


        } else {
            document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = "" + x;
            document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML = "" + y;
            swapped = false;
            return swapped;
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="p1">Loren sump dolor sit mate, sumo unique argument um no. </div><br>

<div id="p2"> Id mes mover elect ram assertion has no. </div><br>

<div id="p3">Ea augur diam usu, nosier arum est an. </div><br>

<button id="trigger">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```